# Ignoring escape sequences

Tags: python, string, null, escaping, backslash

I'm using Python 2.6 and I have a variable which contains a string (I have sent it thorugh sockets and now I want to do something with it).
The problem is that I get the following error:

> TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

After I looked it up I found out that the problem is probably that the string I'm sending contains '\0' but it isn't a literal string that I can just edit with double backslash or adding a 'r' before hand, so is there a way to tell python to ignore the escape sequences and treat the whole thing as string?

(For example - I don't want python to treat the sequence \0 as a null char, but rather I want it to be treated as a backslash char followed by a zero char)

Comment: Why can't you just do `s.replace('\0', '')` (assuming `s` is your string)? In Python 2.7, `chr(0).replace('\0', '')` returns the empty string for me.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I've converted an image to a string and now I'm trying to send it thorugh the internet, therefore I don't have direct access to the string itself.
I don't want to replace \0 with an empty string, I want python to treat it as a backslash char followed by a zero char.

Comment: What do you know about your string? Does it contain "\0" as its last character? Perhaps you can show `repr(s)` here.

Comment: The reported error message occurs when such string is used as a *file name*, not as a *file content*.

Comment: The process is as follows:
- I save an image to a StringIO object. 
- I encode the value of the object using base64.
- I send it using sockets |||
After that I am:
- receiving the whole string using sockets
- decoding the string using base64.
- trying to open the image using the Image.open() function. --> Here I get the error which I've posted above.

Comment: What library are you using? PIL? `Image.open` takes a filename, not image data.

Comment: @dlask I can post here the repr(s) but it is very long... It doesn't end with the "\0".

Comment: The parameter of `Image.open` is a **file name**. What value are you actually using there? The image data?

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental confusion here. How can you have a variable with string contents and simultaneously no access to the string? "I don't want to replace '\0' with the empty string." Of course not. But `chr(0) == '\0'` and `chr(0).replace('\0', '') == ''` which demonstrates that a normal string replacement works, unless something weird is going on.

Comment: @dlask Thank you! You are right I forgot to add the StringIO(s) to the Image.open function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic/typo unless the question is **heavily** edited to reflect the _actual_ problem, rather than a misleading question about replacing escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

Considering all comments it looks like incorrectly used PIL/Pillow API, namely the `Image.open` function that requires **file name** instead of file data.